# Redis set key value and expiry StringSetAsync(key,value,null,when,CommandFlags)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, stackexchange.redis

I'm using StackExchange.Redis latest nuget package in .Net6. I'm getting the redis connection and setting up the key value pair. I'm confused whether we really require 3rd,4th & 5th parameter does it limit to default.

Ex : Option1 :  `_database.StringSetAsync(rediskey, value, null, When.Always, CommandFlags.None);`

If I set it like in the option 1 will the key be expired at some point of time?.Because we are seeing couple of instances where keys are expired and we need to set them again. I'm not sure how redis behaves in terms of expiry. What is the use of using 3rd,4th & 5th parameter

Ex : Option2  : `_database.StringSetAsync(rediskey, value);`

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

I just tried with Option1 seems the keys are expiring in redis. I'm confused which option is better.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use of using 3rd,4th & 5th parameter?

The `StringSetAsync` is an overloaded method in the interface [IDatabaseAsync](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/Interfaces/IDatabaseAsync.cs).

`RedisKey` rediskey: This parameter is the unique key stored in Redis.

`RedisValue` value: This parameter is the value stored in Redis.

`TimeSpan?` expiry: This parameter allows you to specify the expiration duration for the key. If you pass null or don't specify an expiration, the key won't expire unless you delete it from Redis.

`When` when: This parameter indicates when to set the value. For example, `When.Always`(the default) means to set the value regardless of whether the key already exists.

`CommandFlags` flags: These flags are used to control the behavior of the command being sent to Redis. `CommandFlags.None` indicates no special behavior(its the default).

So depending on your requirements: e.g if I want to store value in redis for 10mins I can simply call it like this:

```cs
var result = _database.StringSetAsync(rediskey, value, new TimeSpan(0,10,0)).Result;
```

If I want to store in Redis indefinitely then I would call it like this:

```cs
var result = _database.StringSetAsync(rediskey,value).Result;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. If I pass null in timespan will it be a problem?

Comment: No,it will store in redis indefinitely until you delete it.